# Android : Provide alternative context menu to user

Tags: android, android-intent, android-menu

On android, whenever the user long-clicks on a text field, they get a context menu with options like 'copy' , 'paste', 'select all' etc. Now, I'm aware I cannot add my own items to this menu, system-wide - android won't and shouldn't let me. But I can write my own context menu from scratch, and whenever the user long-clicks on a text view, they will be given two options - 1. System context menu 2. My own menu.

I know this can be done, but I don't know what API calls to use, to achieve this.
Existing applications that do something similar:

1. Swype keyboard: This keyboard application overrides the system keyboard. So when user clicks on a text view to type something, they're given two options, namely - 1. Default system keyboard, or 2. Swype keyboard user installed. User also gets the option to make one of them the default.
2. Similarly, Go Launcher Ex: System wide whenever we press the 'Home' button, we get two options - to display the regular Home screen, or display the Go Launcher Home screen.

Any suggestions, or reference material are highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise you wanted this across all apps. I've deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your examples are accomplished using Intent filters.  However, the EditText's context menu is not shown using an Intent, and therefore cannot be overridden in this way.

You can override the menu in your app using onContextMenu and related API's but there is no way to do so for other apps.

Comment: Thanks! Can there be another hack around this? Can have a background service listen to system wide key presses, and when my service detects a long-press, it will start an activity displaying my custom menu?

Comment: In a rooted environment anything is possible, but the Android platform will not let you intercept input intended for another app, and even if it did it will not let you inspect the other app's window to see if the user was touching an EditText.